# Solving poisson equation in a trivial case: electrostatic

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, dielectric

Consider a dielectric with volume $\Omega$ and frontier $\partial \Omega$ at a potential $V_0$ given. The milieu is at dielectric constant $\epsilon_r(\mathbf{x})$ and contains free charges $\rho_{l}(\mathbf{x})$. We consider that the problem as a cylindrical symmetry, as in the figure. The inner cylinder has radius $b$ and the outer cylinder radius $R$. Because of the cylindrical symmetry, one can say that all the variables depend only on the distance $r$ from the $z$ axis. We then have the following equation : 
$$\nabla ^2 \phi (\mathbf{x})=-\frac{\rho_l(\mathbf{x})}{\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r(\mathbf{x})}, \quad \forall \mathbf{x} \in \Omega$$
I would like to solve this equation in the trivial case when $\epsilon_r(\mathbf{x})=1$ and $\rho_l(\mathbf{x})=\epsilon_0$ in $\Omega$. After several tries, I can't solve this problem...

[image: diagramme of the problem]

Comment: presumably the charge density $\rho$ is NOT the permittivity $\epsilon_0$.

Comment: yes but in this problem I am asked to take the charge density equal to $\epsilon_0$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the geometry of the problem (are the charges only in the inner cylinder?) but I gather  the problem is to find $f$, satisfying $\nabla^{2}f (r)=-1$  in the domain where the charges are present, with a given prescribed value at $R$. Is it some math you can't solve or is there anything else? Could you please clarify?

Comment: exactly, the problem is to solve $\nabla^2 f(r)=-1$ for all r in $[0,R]$ with $V_0$ at $R$. it is more the math I can't solve